# Recv() returns the correct lenght but don't copy the message

Tags: c, sockets, server

I have the next code:

```cpp
while(1) {
    int length=sizeof(client);
    connSock=accept(readSock, (struct sockaddr*) &client,&length);
    if(!fork()) 
    {
        close(readSock);
        char receiveBuff[1000],sendBuff[1000];
        int status;
        int size_buf;
        do {
            status=recv(connSock, receiveBuff, 1000,0);
            printf("%d status \n",status);
            printf("%s recv buff\n", receiveBuff);
            memcpy(sendBuff,receiveBuff,sizeof(receiveBuff));
            send(connSock, &sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), 0);

        }while (status!=0);
        close(connSock);
        exit(0);
    }
    close(connSock);
}
```

I am trying to send a message `"Test"` and the `recv()` function returns 4 (the correct length), but when I try to print the `receiveBuffer` it doesn't work. This is the output:

```
4 status 
h: recv buff
```

This is the code from the client side:

```cpp
void Client_Connector::Start_Connection()
{
    this->sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    bzero(&this->server,sizeof(server));
    this->server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1", &this->server.sin_addr);
    server.sin_port=htons(2500);
    int status=connect(sock,(struct sockaddr*) &server, sizeof(server));
    if (status==0)
        cout<<"Sunteti conectat! \n";
    else
        Eroare("Eroare de conexiune! Conexiunea nu s-a putut realiza.");
}
    
void Client_Connector::send_Buffer(char* sendMessage)
{
    int i;
    i=send(sock, &sendMessage,strlen(sendMessage)+1,0);
    cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

And just call the function:

```cpp
connecter.Start_Connection();
string sendmsg("Test");
sendmsg+="\0";
connecter.send_Buffer((char*)sendmsg.c_str());
```

Comment: What output did you expect? What are you actually sending? Also remember that TCP is a *streaming* protocol and that you might need multiple `recv` calls to receive all data.

Comment: On another couple of notes, are you sure that the data you receive will be null-terminated like a string? And `&sendBuff` in the `send` call is wrong, it should be either plain `sendBuff` or `&sendBuff[0]`.

Comment: *"I am trying to send a message "Test" "* - please show how this message is actually sent, not just how you try to receive it. Also `receiveBuff` is not initialized with 0 and thus will contain random data. Specifically it might contain `\r` which causes overwriting what was already written on the same line and thus messes with the visible output.

Comment: Another couple of notes, if you have null-terminated strings you want to transmit don't send e.g. `sizeof(sendBuff)` number of bytes. That will send the whole buffer, including the parts of it you haven't initialized. Instead use `strlen(sendBuff) + 1` to only send the string itself *including* the null-terminator.

Comment: I edited and added the client side code

Comment: The client code is C++, and in C++ when you feel the need to use a C-style cast (like you do in `(char*)sendmsg.c_str()`) you should take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong. Instead pass a constant reference to the actual string object `sendmsg` to the function, and use `c_str()` and `length() + 1` in the call to `send`.

Comment: Also, it has always been that the string returned by `c_str()` would be null-terminated. And since the C++11 standard all `std::string` objects are guaranteed to include the terminator. So `sendmsg+="\0";` is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't actually send the string, you send the *pointer* to the string:

```
i=send(sock, &sendMessage,strlen(sendMessage),0);
```

Here `&sendMessage` will be a pointer to the variable `sendMessage`, not a pointer to the first character of the string.

Simple solution:

```
i = send(sock, sendMessage, strlen(sendMessage) + 1, 0);
```

That will send the actual string contents, including the terminating null character.

---

I also recommend you take a couple of steps back, and refresh your knowledge of arrays and pointers and the associated operators.